# simple query broke for no reason?

Tags: php, mysql

These all echo correctly but the query doesn't insert anything? it use to work and just broke.

```
echo $social_id;
echo $name;
echo $email;
echo $social_network;
echo $profile_pic;

mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (social_id, name, email, social_network, profile_pic)
             VALUES ('$social_id', '$name','$email', '$social_network','$profile_pic')");
$user_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: You're exiting before executing the query.. Remove `exit`.

Comment: the exit() was for debug... i took it out and doesn't work i just accidently copied and pasted this one before I moved it.

Comment: Syntactically, everything appears to be fine. Print `mysql_error()` aafter executing `mysql_query`, and you should find your answer. Most likely you have an offending character in content of your query.

Comment: nothing happens. i get a blank page and nothing new in my database? :(

Comment: not sure why i got so many negatives. the answer wasn't even the exit()... it was because my database had social_id set to int and the int number was actually a string sent from facebook in the form of an int.

Answer (score 4):

Try removing the `exit()` call:

```
echo $social_id;
echo $name;
echo $email;
echo $social_network;
echo $profile_pic;
exit();
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (social_id, name, email, social_network, profile_pic)
             VALUES ('$social_id', '$name','$email', '$social_network','$profile_pic')");

$user_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: @minitech: Thanks, I didn't know that SO's formatting worked for any `<code>` block.

Comment: i've taken it out and moved it to debug. still doesn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PHP expert, but is it because you have an `exit()` call before the insert statement runs, and therefore the query is never reached?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `exit()` directly before your query, so the query is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your error logs if you have disabled PHP errors being displayed on the screen.
2. Use mysql_errno() and mysql_error() to view any errors that may be reported when PHP attempts to select or query the database like:

   ```
   <?php
   $social_id = "test";
   $name = "Bob";
   $email = "myself@localhost";
   $social_network = "facespace";
   $profile_pic = "me.png";

   $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "roots", "for_the_cubs");
   if(!$conn){
       die('Could not connect to the database');    
   }

   mysql_select_db("mydb", $conn);
   echo mysql_errno($conn) . " : " . mysql_error($conn);

   mysql_query("INSERT INTO users 
            (social_id, name, email, social_network, profile_pic)
           VALUES 
            ('$social_id', '$name','$email', '$social_network','$profile_pic')");
   echo mysql_errno($conn) . " : " . mysql_error($conn);

   ?>
   ```
3. Double-check to ensure the mysql extension is enabled in php.ini.
4. Check to see if there have been any changes to your database or php version.

It may be possible that something was upgraded on the server and the mysql extension was not re-added, opting for PDO or mysqli instead